# How to rollback in phinx

Tags: sql, migration, rollback, phinx

I want to rollback to previous stage. I Google and found this command

```
phinx breakpoint -e development
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phinx have this rollback command.

```
phinx rollback -e development
```

You can get further details from documentation.[Phinx rollback](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/commands.html#the-rollback-command)